# Setting different text sizes for different screen sizes (programatically created TextViews)

Tags: java, android

I have many TextViews created programatically, but I cannot find out how I could change the text size according to what screen size the device is.

Example: I have layout_sw300dp and layout_sw600dp folders containing individual screen designs to fit according to the phone used. But since I programatically create TextViews, I cannot alter the TextSize for different screen sizes.

How can I fix this matter? Is it possible to have different /res/values/styles.xml for different screens, that way I can attach the style via code and define the styles individually in XML, if so, what is the folder layout?

Comment: Yes - You can create different styles.xml by using values-xxx directory structures. This will allow you to have the control you need if the automatic scaling provided by sp is not enough.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're setting the text size of the TextView using 'sp' then the text should be automatically scaled.